# What's the proper style to indent Ruby on Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indentation

I've noticed that Ruby on Rails code has 2 spaces indentation, e.g.:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      ...
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Is this a convention to have 2 spaces ? (I've used to indent with Tab, which is usually 4 spaces.)

Bonus:
Does anyone know how to change the Tab size from 4 spaces to 2 spaces in e text editor?

Comment: In e you click on the text that says "Soft Tabs:4" at the bottom of the window and change it to `2`.

Comment: @fullware What? In e-texteditor tabs can be set to any number of spaces for display purposes. As the OP asked how to change the setting away from 4 spaces, the display at the bottom of the window would show as 4.

Comment: Yes you can configure an editor to convert a tab to x-spaces or to display a tab character to as many spaces as you want. But if you use any unix utilities, a tab character will be expanded to 8. It's a mess unless all tabs are converted to spaces. Have you ever noticed how source files look horribly indented when you use the `cat` command?

Comment: What does "soft" in "Soft Tabs" mean ?

Comment: Soft tabs means a tab keypress is converted into a specified number of spaces. So there are no tab characters (\t) in file. This is the "compatible" way to use the "tab key" for indentation when you're not using 8-space tabs.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, two spaces per indentation level is the [Ruby community standard](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml#indentation).

Comment: A simple question: Is obligatory the indentation in Ruby on Rails as in Python?

Comment: @andreshg112 No, whitespace (other than newlines) is largely irrelevant in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I always indent 2 spaces instead of tabs. It looks a little nicer.

Rails itself uses the same convention.